# HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode return Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#

```
string htmlEncode = HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode(value);

return Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Value is number or string. I use this in console app. Why i can't use HttpContext.Current.Server.HtmlEncode?

Comment: Are you calling this from the server-side code that processes the client request? In other cases the HttpContext.Current will be null. That's probably why you have the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Console does not have `HttpContext`, so you'll have to find [some alternative](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73z22y6h.aspx).

For example:

```
string myString = "<b>hello</b>";
Console.WriteLine(System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(myString));
```

Answer (score 2):

Because its a Console app, the HttpContext won't be there. For HtmlEncoding you can use [HttpUtility Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) instead of the Server.HtmlEncode method.

Answer (score 1):

Because HttpContext is the object that is provided to you by the web server. So you cant use it in Console app.